# What length units can we use in JS?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have created a canvas where I will draw shapes with the `<canvas>` tag, and its size is controlled by js. I want to resize it such as it covers the full desktop. However, units like vh and vw don't work here. Please suggest a way. Here's the js code:

```
var programCode = function(processingInstance) {
with (processingInstance) {
  size(400, 400); 
  frameRate(30);
```

}};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## JS

Use window event resize:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);
```

You should use document.documentElement.clientHeight/Width because thay take scrollbar into consideration when window.innerHeight/Width do not.

By the way you can use this:

```
  let scrollHeight = window.innerWidth && document.documentElement.clientWidth ? 
  Math.min(window.innerWidth, document.documentElement.clientWidth) : 
  window.innerWidth || 
  document.documentElement.clientWidth || 
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth;
```

Or this:

```
let scrollHeight = Math.max(
document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight,
document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight );
```

You can just replace width and height words with each other in the above example

## CSS

```
* { margin:0; padding:0; } /* to remove the top and left whitespace */

html, body { width:100%; height:100%; } /* just to be sure these are full screen*/

canvas { display:block; } /* To remove the scrollbars */
```

Comment: Thanks! Anyways, where did you learn js from?

Answer (score -1):

Use `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` to resize the canvas from JavaScript.

Comment: That is not what the question is asking.